# Inserting, updating and removing from a complex embedded collection in MongoDB from Node using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm developing a demo app in NodeJS which uses MongoDB, currently used modules are Express and Mongoose.

The main idea is to remake a PHP+MySQL app, where the MySQL database consist of three tables, on a 1:N relation: Company->Field->Item

The example datacollection looks like:

```
[
{"id": 1,"name": "DemoCompanyOne", "fields":[
    {"id": 1, "location": "DemoLocationOne", "items":[
        {"_id": 1,"name": "DemoItemOne","price": 1500,"count": 16,"date": "2013-11-02 16:53:19"}, 
        {"_id": 2,"name": "DemoItemTwo","price": 890,"count": 211,"date": "2013-11-02 16:53:19"}
    ]}, 
    {"id": 2, "location": "DemoLocationTwo", "items":[
        {"_id": 3,"name": "DemoItemThree","price": 9990,"count": 10,"date": "2013-11-02 19:12:40"}, 
        {"_id": 4,"name": "DemoItemFour","price": 2500,"count": 20,"date": "2013-11-02 19:12:42"}
    ]}
]}, 
{"id": 2,"name": "DemoCompanyTwo", "fields":[
    {"id": 3, "location": "DemoLocationThree", "items":[
        {"_id": 5,"name": "DemoItemFive","price": 79000,"count": 11,"date": "2013-11-02 16:56:13"}, 
        {"_id": 6,"name": "DemoItemSix","price": 649,"count": 8760,"date": "2013-11-02 16:56:13"}, 
        {"_id": 7,"name": "DemoItemSeven","price": 149,"count": 4320,"date": "2013-11-02 16:57:19"}
    ]}
]}
]
```

I've made schemes in Mongoose, as:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId

var Items = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    count: Number,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var Field = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    location: String,
    items: [Items]
});

var Company = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    Fields: [Field]
});

var cmp = mongoose.model('company', Company, "company");
var flds = mongoose.model('fields', Field, "fields");
var itm = mongoose.model('items', Items, "items");
```

Please note, that the _id of items was changed to ObjectId in Mongo, as I hoped that this would help me to handle these embedded collections better - it havent.

I want to insert items to specified locations, or increment the count number of a selected item, or remove a selected item.

The company_id and field_id is included in the URL, as:

```
app.post('/:company_id/:field_id', function(req, res) { ... })
```

Inside this handler, I separate requests, like:

```
app.post('/:company_id/:field_id', function(req, res) {
var company = req.params.company_id;
var field = req.params.field_id;
if (req.body.new != null)
{
    cmp.findOne({}).where('id').equals(company).where('fields.id').equals(field).exec(function(err, comps) {
        if (comps == null)
        { res.render('error', {title: 'Error!', msg: 'No such field!'}); }
        else
        { 
            i=0;
            while (i < comps.fields.length && comps.fields[i].id != field)
            { i++; }
            var r = new itm({"_id": "", "name": req.body.name, "price":req.body.price, "count":req.body.count});
            comps.fields[i].items.push(r);
            comps.save();
        }
    });
}
else if (req.body.mod != null)
{
    //...
}
else if (req.body.del != null)
{
    //...
}
res.redirect('/'+company+'/'+field);
})
```

As you see, on item adding i'm using linear search to find the field, where i can push the newly made item... this is very-very ugly, i'm sure there must be a lot simpler way to do this...

And, what about incrementation or removing? I dont want to to it the same way...

And, for a fourth question: what do you think about the IDs? How to implement them? Should I use ObjectIds everywhere, or it isnt necessary anywhere at all?

Any help and ideas is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vision is you use embedded documents if they are almost static. Your objects look dynamic to me, so I suggest you try using document references instead:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId

var Items = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    count: Number,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    field: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Field'}
});

var Field = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    location: String,
    company: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company'}
    items: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Items'}]
});

var Company = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    fields: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Field'}]
});
```

So you keep a parent reference like in MySQL + keep children references as an array to populate fast. Thus you won't have to mess up with nested documents:

```
Field.findOne({_id: fieldid}).exec(function(err, field){...do whatever you need...})
```

Also, I do not recommend to call your model "Items". Call it with singular, like "Item".

Comment: sorry for the late answer: it took some time to rethink and implement this solution, but it works fine, thank you very much: dropping the idea of embedded docs would have been the last, but the code is **a lot** simpler now.

Comment: No problem, but also please note, that embedded documents are being retrieved way faster than documents connected with references. So sometimes you might want to use them, for example, to keep different contact details for users (email, twitter, facebook, physical addresses etc.)